# Java encode special character in a String with UTF-8 character

Tags: java, utf-8

```
 String original = "This is my string valúe";
```

I'm trying to encode the above string to UTF-8 equivalent but to replace only special character (ú) with -- "&#250 ;" in this case.

I've tried using the below but I get an error:

> Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !Bytes: 0xFA 0x20 0x63 0x61

Code:

```
    String original = new String("This is my string valúe");

    byte ptext[] = original.getBytes("UTF-8");
    String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8"); 

    System.out.println("Output : " + value);

    This is my string valúe
```

Comment: @user4015632 why down vote

Comment: what is the reason for down vote?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) and formatted io like

```
String original = "This is my string valúe";
System.out.printf("Output : %s%n", original.replace("ú", "&#250;"));
```

Which outputs (as I think you wanted)

```
Output : This is my string val&#250;e
```

Comment: what if I have another special character like " ñ ". Instead of hardcode these is there a way I can convert any special character with its equivalent UTF-8 value?

Comment: Take a look at [`StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) and `escapeHtml`.

Comment: [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) from package `org.apache.commons.lang3` is **deprecated** and use [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) from package `org.apache.commons.text` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to use XML character entities.

[Appache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) has a method for this (in StringEscapeUtils).

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to encode the above string to UTF-8 equivalent but to replace only >special character ( ú ) with -- "&#250 ;" in this case.

I'm not sure what encoding "&#250 ;" is but have you tried looking at the [`URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class? It won't encode the string exactly the way you asked but it gets rid of the spooky character.

Comment: URLEncoder class encodes plain text with all + signs etc, which really didn't work. But StringEscapeUtils more suitable for a Html page text or titles

Answer (score -3):

Could you please try the below lines:

```
 byte ptext[] = original.getBytes("UTF8");
 String value = new String(ptext, "UTF8");
```

Comment: I still get this -->  This is my string valúe .  Desired solution - > This is my string val&#250;e